# Can we directly print from alive pdf instead of generating the pdf

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, alivepdf

Is there a way to directly print using alive pdf (by passing the step where it saves the datagrid in pdf). Right now I am using Alive Pdf for generating PDF from datagrid and its doing a great job. Since flex printing by itself sucks I was wondering if I could directly print using Alive PDF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure the answer to this is no. You cannot print a pdf without first generating it; it may not need to be saved to disk, however that sure will be the easiest way.

Comment: hmm it makes sense... could you suggest some other way to print apart from Flex print? Thanks.

Comment: You could try generating the pdf, displaying it in a webpage and then telling the browser to print using JS.

Comment: Well. I can try that but the other thing is that I want the print ability for clients who do not have pdf installed on their machines. Thanks.

Comment: Dont think you'll be able to that unless you actually render the pdf in flash, another approach to this might be to use some existing online service to translate it to html.